# Error:Message="The Admin Username specified is not allowed." Target="adminUsername"

Tags: azure, terraform

While I'm creating VM in azure using terraform getting above error. Please help me in this.
code:
admin_username      = var.user-name

Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine : Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The Admin Username specified is not allowed." Target="adminUsername"

Comment: What is `var.user-name` and can you provide full definition of your VM resource?

Comment: variable "user-name" {
   default="test"
}

Comment: the issue resolved after giving username with out test

Answer (score 0):

> admin_ssh_key {
> username   = "ubuntu"
> public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")   }
> admin_username=var.user-name must & should be same